# Can the word 'centerpiece' be used figuratively?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, translation

The word 'centerpiece' refers to the decorative piece in the center of a dining table. In the German translation ('Kernstück'), we can also use it figuratively, e.g., to refer to the central point of a text or theory. For example, we may say:

> Comparative advantage is a centerpiece of theories on international trade.

Does this usage also exist in English? If not, what would be a better translation ('mainstay' perhaps)?

Comment: I would say yes, but generally (since there is only one centerpiece) things would be considered "**the** centerpiece".

Comment: I see no reason why any word wouldn't be able to be used figuratively.

Comment: @Uhtred Paradoxically, I cannot think of a way to use _figuratively_ figuratively…

Comment: Can't almost *anything* be used figuratively in the right context?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *The Winter Olympic figure skating team  skated figuratively through the interview.* I wouldn't say that's a literal use of *figuratively*. ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford I suppose you could argue that’s the _only_ literal use of the word, and the more common sense of the word is the figurative one.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In that sentence, how can either *skated* or *figuratively* be taken in a literal sense? The team didn't *actually* skate (let alone skate in figures) through the interview. They most likely sat in their chairs. You asked how *figuratively* could be used figuratively. As far as I can tell, that is an example—because it's not being used literally . . . (Of course, I used a very specific sense of *figuratively*.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I missed the interview bit – the figure skating team bit threw me off. But then it’s really just the standard meaning of _figuratively_ (i.e., ‘not literally’) because they didn’t actually skate. But arguably that use **is** figurative; the most literal sense of the word would be ‘related to figures’, and figures of speech are essentially figurative figures.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So, it could be considered *literally figurative*. Perhaps there is something, in mathematics, that's a *figurative literal*. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lexico (The Oxford Dictionaries) [says](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/centrepiece) that it can be used figuratively.

> **centrepiece** (US centerpiece)
>   NOUN
>
> **1** An ornament or display placed in the middle of a dining table.
>
> **1.1** An item, issue, etc. intended to be a focus of attention.
>   *a domestic programme with healthcare as the centrepiece*